# Array when moving a multidimensional array

Tags: laravel-5

I need a make another array of this when traveling a multidimensional array and filter of this array element.

Here is the structure:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => Size:32
    [1] => Size:34
    [2] => Size:35
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [0] => Color:red
    [1] => Color:red
    [2] => Color:green
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 8
  )
)
```

Comment: i want array like this 

$string[0] = Size:32,Color:red,5
$string[1] = Size:34,Color:red,4
$string[2] = Size:35,Color:green,8

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 $a1[0] = ['Color:red','Color:green','Color:blue'];
 $a1[1] = ['Size:32','Size:34','Size:35'];
 $a1[2] = [5,4,8];
 $string = [];
     for ($i = 0; $i<count($a1[0]);$i++){
        $string[$i] = $a1[0][$i].','.$a1[1][$i].','.$a1[2][$i];   
     }     

return print_r($string);
```